# Combining batches of sauerkraut

Tags: food-safety, sauerkraut

I make sauerkraut regularly, this last batch has too much celery seed. I use celery seed instead of caraway. I like the flavor better. I have 2 quarts left. Can I make a new batch of sauerkraut and mix the previous batch into it to take down the overpowering celery seed astringency? I usually have my sauerkraut go about 7 days then put it in quart jars in the back of the fridge and use a quart at a time. I weigh my cabbage in grams and use a 2 percent regular ground pink salt ratio. If I can do this, how would I handle the salt ratio so it is not too salty and is the proper ph for safety? My thinking was to make the new batch to proper salt weight ratio, then add the new celery seed in. When the taste is right add the old batch in. percolate until it is a flavor I like then bottle it all up again.  I didn't want to do this if it can not be done safely. Ultimately I figured I could mix the two finished batches together. What say you all?

Comment: You haven’t said how old your first batch was and how long you take to eat each batch. I find sauerkraut very forgiving and, as long as the first batch is still pretty fresh and has been well-maintained, I think your plan is very sound. You’ll be cutting back the quantity of celery in the second batch, right? When you talk about tasting it for celery, remember the flavour continues to develop long after adding it (the seeds only gradually release their flavour) so tasting as you make it has limited value.

Comment: When I say ‘well-maintained’ I mean always ensuring the liquids cover the solids (scrape down and re-submerge each time you use some and don’t “steal” too much liquid each time). Throw out sauerkraut if it starts to look or smell mouldy, or develops any new odours you haven’t smelled before.

Comment: The old batch is about a month old. I eat kraut every day and always in my salads. 3 large heads come out to about 6-8 pounds. I am down to one quart that is about 1 and a half months old. I make my kraut properly following all the rules ........I have decided to do up the new batch, and when it is done mix them all together and refrigerate. Then I feel safe.